# How to find child node text in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get text from child node from the element tree but when i try to get specific element it is getting empty array.

Here is my command in Chrome Console : $x('//*[@id="mainform"]/child::text()[10]')

then I need to get textContent value which is Memorable word and I dont know how to get it.

Any suggestion appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `$x('string(//*[@id="mainform"]/child::text()[10])')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting a list of elements, you just need to visit the one you need:

```
$x('//*[@id="mainform"]/child::text()[10]')[0]
```